# Detect if an object is a ValueTuple

Tags: c#, .net, valuetuple

I have a use case where I need to check if a value is a C# 7 ValueTuple, and if so, loop through each of the items.  I tried checking with `obj is ValueTuple` and `obj is (object, object)` but both of those return false.  I found that I could use `obj.GetType().Name` and check if it starts with `"ValueTuple"` but that seems lame to me.  Any alternatives would be welcomed.

I also have the issue of getting each item.  I attempted to get `Item1` with the solution found here: [How do I check if a property exists on a dynamic anonymous type in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956648/how-do-i-check-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-anonymous-type-in-c) but `((dynamic)obj).GetType().GetProperty("Item1")` returns null.  My hope was that I could then do a `while` to get each item.  But this does not work.  How can I get each item?

**Update - more code**

```
if (item is ValueTuple) //this does not work, but I can do a GetType and check the name
{
    object tupleValue;
    int nth = 1;
    while ((tupleValue = ((dynamic)item).GetType().GetProperty($"Item{nth}")) != null && //this does not work
        nth <= 8)      
    {
        nth++;
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: ValueTuple is a Structure, that's why you need GetType(). Can you post more code ?

Comment: Calling `((dynamic)item).GetType().GetProperties()` returns an empty array...  :(

Comment: Those `Item1` `Item2` etc are not properties - they are fields. So you have to do `GetType().GetField("Item1")...`. Casting to dynamic is not needed.

Comment: I can't help but think that this might be an X-Y problem.

Comment: You may want to consider having a specific method to deal with your type restriction. You can then make it a generic with a restriction like `where T : struct`.

Comment: Also, "Importantly, the tuple field names aren't part of the runtime representation of tuples, but are tracked only by the compiler. As a result, the field names will not be available to a 3rd party observer of a tuple instance - such as reflection or dynamic code." https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/features/tuples.md#name-erasure-at-runtime-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my solution to the problem.  A PCL compatible extension class.  Special thanks to @dasblinkenlight and @Evk for helping me out!

```
public static class TupleExtensions
{
    private static readonly HashSet<Type> ValueTupleTypes = new HashSet<Type>(new Type[]
    {
        typeof(ValueTuple<>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,>),
        typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,,>)
    });

    public static bool IsValueTuple(this object obj) => IsValueTupleType(obj.GetType());
    public static bool IsValueTupleType(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && ValueTupleTypes.Contains(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }

    public static List<object> GetValueTupleItemObjects(this object tuple) => GetValueTupleItemFields(tuple.GetType()).Select(f => f.GetValue(tuple)).ToList();
    public static List<Type> GetValueTupleItemTypes(this Type tupleType) => GetValueTupleItemFields(tupleType).Select(f => f.FieldType).ToList();    
    public static List<FieldInfo> GetValueTupleItemFields(this Type tupleType)
    {
        var items = new List<FieldInfo>();

        FieldInfo field;
        int nth = 1;
        while ((field = tupleType.GetRuntimeField($"Item{nth}")) != null)
        {
            nth++;
            items.Add(field);
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: better solution is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43341177/how-to-iterate-over-tuple-items

Answer (score 13):

Structures do not inherit in C#, so `ValueTuple<T1>`, `ValueTuple<T1,T2>`, `ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3>` and so on are distinct types that do not inherit from `ValueTuple` as their base. Hence, `obj is ValueTuple` check fails.

If you are looking for `ValueTuple` with arbitrary type arguments, you can check if the class is `ValueTuple<,...,>` as follows:

```
private static readonly Set<Type> ValTupleTypes = new HashSet<Type>(
    new Type[] { typeof(ValueTuple<>), typeof(ValueTuple<,>),
                 typeof(ValueTuple<,,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,,>),
                 typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,>),
                 typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,,>)
    }
);
static bool IsValueTuple2(object obj) {
    var type = obj.GetType();
    return type.IsGenericType
        && ValTupleTypes.Contains(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
}
```

To get sub-items based on the type you could use an approach that is not particularly fast, but should do the trick:

```
static readonly IDictionary<Type,Func<object,object[]>> GetItems = new Dictionary<Type,Func<object,object[]>> {
    [typeof(ValueTuple<>)] = o => new object[] {((dynamic)o).Item1}
,   [typeof(ValueTuple<,>)] = o => new object[] {((dynamic)o).Item1, ((dynamic)o).Item2}
,   [typeof(ValueTuple<,,>)] = o => new object[] {((dynamic)o).Item1, ((dynamic)o).Item2, ((dynamic)o).Item3}
,   ...
};
```

This would let you do this:

```
object[] items = null;
var type = obj.GetType();
if (type.IsGeneric && GetItems.TryGetValue(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), out var itemGetter)) {
    items = itemGetter(obj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, although I will probably stick to the type name check, as it gets any tuple.  Do you know how I can get each item though?

Comment: @JamesEsh Did you try `((dynamic)obj).Item1`?

Comment: Yes!  Any ideas on how to do it dynamically?

Comment: @JamesEsh See if the little trick with the dictionary works for you.

Comment: I wonder if doing `((dynamic)obj).Item1` is faster\slower\about the same as doing `obj.GetType().GetField("Item1").GetValue(obj)`?

Comment: @Evk I think one will get roughly the same low speed in both cases. `dynamic` may be a bit faster because the compiler could skip a few checks in the sequence of calls that retrieve the value, but the common overhead of getting a field by name would probably dominate anyway.

Comment: dasblinkenlight & @Evk see my answer for my PCL extension.  Thanks for yall's help!

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the part of the question "How can I get each item?"...

Both ValueTuple and Tuple implement `ITuple`, which has a length property and an indexer property.  So a the following console app code lists the values to the console:

```
// SUT (as a local function)
IEnumerable<object> GetValuesFromTuple(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ITuple tuple) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < tuple.Length; i++)
        yield return tuple[i];
}

// arrange
var valueTuple = (StringProp: "abc", IntProp: 123, BoolProp: false, GuidProp: Guid.Empty);

// act
var values = GetValuesFromTuple(valueTuple);

// assert (to console)
Console.WriteLine($"Values = '{values.Count()}'");

foreach (var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Value = '{value}'");
}
```

Console output:

```
Values = '4'
Value = 'abc'
Value = '123'  
Value = 'False'  
Value = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that ITuple is only available since 4.7.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont like building hash tables upfront, something like this will work:

```
public static bool IsTupleType(this Type type)
{
    return typeof(ITuple).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}

public static bool IsValueTupleType(this Type type)
{
    return type.IsValueType && type.IsTupleType();
}

public static bool IsReferenceTupleType(this Type type)
{
    return type.IsClass && type.IsTupleType();
}
```

Efficient, and easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

hackish one liner

```
type.Name.StartsWith("ValueTuple`")
```

(can be extended to check the digit at the end)

Comment: This was already stated in the question: _I found that I could use obj.GetType().Name and check if it starts with "ValueTuple" but that seems lame to me._

Comment: Ah I see sorry I missed that, tbh while hackish it is probably totally solid