# How to check if a list of ValueTuple is type of List<ValueTuple> in C# 7

Tags: c#, types, valuetuple

How could I check if a list of ValueTuple is type of `List<ValueTuple>`, without regarding the type of parameters.

It could be :

```
new List<(150, "test")>()
new List<("testy", "test", 148)>()
new List<(true, "blablabla")>()
```

What I've tried

```
 public static bool IsTupleType2(this object tuple)
 {
     return tuple is ITuple;
 }
```

This extension method works on a ValueTuple object

So I tried with `List<ITuple>` but it doesn't work

```
 public static bool IsTupleType2(this object tuple)
 {
     return tuple is List<ITuple>;
 }
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might need to check "is generic list" and "is the first type parameter an ITuple" (using reflection) separately.

Comment: Note that `Tuple<T1, T2>` and friends also implement `ITuple` -- so if you're using `ITuple`, your tests will return true for e.g. a `List<Tuple<int, string>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fairly simple (if slightly long-winded) way of doing it:

```
private static readonly Type[] tupleTypes = new[]
{
    typeof(ValueTuple<>), typeof(ValueTuple<,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,>),
    typeof(ValueTuple<,,,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,>),
    typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,>), typeof(ValueTuple<,,,,,,,>)
};

public static bool IsListOfValueTuple(Type type)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
    {
        var arg = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        return arg.IsGenericType && tupleTypes.Contains(arg.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }
    return false;
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsListOfValueTuple(typeof(List<(string, int)>)));
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, a future-proofing and non-hard-coding way to retrieve the tuple types is through this ugly piece of code:


`private static readonly Type[] tupleTypes = typeof(ValueTuple).Assembly.GetTypes().ToList().Where(t => t.Name.Contains(nameof(ValueTuple)) && t.IsGenericType).ToArray();`

Comment: @Rekkon `GetTypes().ToList()` is going to be expensive, and is unnecessary - `GetTypes().Where(...)` does the same thing. Also it's be better to use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`, I think? And test for `"System.ValueTuple\`"`

Comment: Correct, `ToList()` is unnecessary and the value tuple types always start with `ValueTuple`, here's the fixed: `private static readonly Type[] tupleTypes = typeof(ValueTuple).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith(nameof(ValueTuple)) && t.IsGenericType).ToArray();`

Comment: @Rekkon But if you're doing that, you might as well look at the generic argument of the `List<T>` and see whether its name starts with `System.ValueTuple\`1` (and whether it's in the right assembly)

Comment: I've tested it and the Name property returns `ValueTuple\`n` where n is the number of type arguments.

Comment: @Rekkon do not do this. Assembly scanning is terribly slow (and on top, GetTypes might throw depending on load context. I suggest a simple approach like https://stackoverflow.com/a/75852077/661933 for future-proofing. In short, look for `ITuple` interface and ensure type is value type.